# Rails where has related model with specific values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a recipe model that has many ingredients through recipe_ingredients.

How can I get, efficiently, all recipes that

- have butter and chocolate
- have butter but not chocolate
- have neither butter nor chocolate

There will be millions of recipes, so I was hoping to get the results I need with just one query and not having to do a select or reject in the result for the first condition.
Like:

```
Recipe.joins(:ingredients)
  .where(ingredients: { name: 'chocolate' })
  .select{ |recipe| recipe.ingredients.pluck(:name).include?('butter') }
```

Also, I need it to work for when the user selects more than 2 ingredients.
I'm open to store the data in a different way if that will make the search more efficient - or do it with a direct sql query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For recipes having butter and chocolate:

```
Recipes.joins(:ingredients)
  .where(ingredients: { name: ['chocolate','butter'] })
```

For recipes having butter but not chocolate:

```
Recipes.joins(:ingredients)
  .where(ingredients: { name: 'butter' })
  .where.not(ingredients: { name: 'chocolate' })
```

For recipes having neither butter or chocolate:

```
Recipes.joins(:ingredients)
  .where.not(ingredients: { name: ['chocolate', 'butter'] })
```

Hope this helps!